# Cannot stored the value in class object when button press in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, oop, c#-4.0

I wrote the code with `ASP.NET C#` for test stored the value in class object. But I got the result are different what I know. Is any one know what force on this or any solution can do this ?

below is my code:

html:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication10._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text="Speak:">
                        </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="tbOutput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddHello1" runat="server" Text="Hello1" OnClick="btnAddHello1_Click" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddHello2" runat="server" Text="Hello2" OnClick="btnAddHello2_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication10
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        public class clsPerson
        {
            public string strSpeak = "";
        }
        clsPerson clsPerson1 = new clsPerson();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          if (!IsPostBack)
          {
                clsPerson1.strSpeak += "Hello";
                Console.WriteLine("strSpeak(NotIsPostBack) = " + clsPerson1.strSpeak);
                tbOutput.Text = clsPerson1.strSpeak;
            }
          else
          {
                clsPerson1.strSpeak += "Hello3";
                Console.WriteLine("strSpeak(IsPostBack) = " + clsPerson1.strSpeak);
                tbOutput.Text = clsPerson1.strSpeak;
            }
        }

        protected void btnAddHello1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clsPerson1.strSpeak += "+Hello1";
            Console.WriteLine("strSpeak(Hello1 Button) = " + clsPerson1.strSpeak);
            tbOutput.Text = clsPerson1.strSpeak;
        }

        protected void btnAddHello2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clsPerson1.strSpeak += "+Hello2";
            Console.WriteLine("strSpeak(Hello2 Button) = " + clsPerson1.strSpeak);
            tbOutput.Text = clsPerson1.strSpeak;
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
default output is Hello
when press hello1 button, output is "Hello3+Hello1"
when press hello2 button, output is "Hello3+Hello2"
```

My problem is why the string of class cannot keep the value inside.

Is any way which let the string of class can keep the value inside with between button pressed.

Comment: Web pages are stateless (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101337/whats-the-difference-between-stateful-and-stateless). You need to store the values of variables in a session, cookie, hidden field, querystring etc to keep them on form post (PostBack).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks VDWWD, I am new in ASP.NET. Base on your suggested. I will use session to keep the data in Web Page.